# Image Processing In c#,.net

Tags: image, image-processing, c#-2.0

I want to create a small application that allows me to insert an image on top of another image.And also i want to insert some text as well.

So can someone points me out where to start.Is there any open source libraries that allows me to do this task?.

I am after a solution that can be implemented in C#,Visual Studio .net.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class.

For example:

```
using(var oldImage = Bitmap.FromFile(path))
using(var newImage = new Bitmap(250, 250))
using(var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)) {
    graphics.DrawImage(oldImage, 10, 15);
    graphics.DrawString("Hello, world!", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Red, 0, 0);
    newImage.Save(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [ImageMagick.Net](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/).  Lotsa stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be OK using [System.Drawing.Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) if you don't need anything too fancy.